Does "In these past (few?) months/years/days..." require "few"?
Is it natural and idiomatic to say "In these past months / years / days / weeks / decades / [other time period]" without including the word "few"?
I thought one always had to add "few/several/[some qualifier]" in "past few X", but I found some reputable sources suggesting I could drop it https://ludwig.guru/s/in+these+past+months , https://ludwig.guru/s/in+these+past+years , https://ludwig.guru/s/in+these+past+weeks .
The exception is for "days", where there was only 1 occurrence, so it might as well be unidiomatic https://ludwig.guru/s/in+these+past+days

You need to include some additional phrase to limit the past if you don't want to sound quaint by saying "these past days", "these past weeks" (at least in AmE).

In recent years...
In these past few months...
In these last couple of weeks

Without some modifier and using these:

In these past months
In these last weeks

those phrases sound a pensive, or even homiletic note.
And I don't think you could get away with  "in these past years" unless "these" referred to something earlier in the conversation.

It has been five years since we met at class reunion. In these past years, many of you ...


I disagree with your need. There are dozens of written instances in Google Books of, for example, in these past days I have. Having said that, I certainly wouldn't advise a non-native speaker t use such stilted phrasing. in recent days is far more natural.

@FumbleFingers "These" is such a limiting word, but only if it has a referent earlier in the conversation.  It cannot stand on its own, except in phrases like "These days, you're lucky if you can find one at any price."

Without such a temporal reference, "these past days", "these past months", "these past years" is quaint.  I've added that to the answer.

@FumbleFingers - 'I've seen more arses in these last weeks than I would have if I worked on an arse farm.' - AL Kennedy in the Guardian 11 Feb 2024 (funny account of her recovery from an operation when she was stuck indoors with only cable TV for amusement)

@FumbleFingers -  She [Virginia Woolf] has been really very ill these last weeks & was terrified that she was going mad again. It was, I suppose, the strain of the war & finishing her book 1941 letter to Vita Sackville-West on the day of Woolf's death

Could be a translatlantic thing. Reminds me of how the old folks talked on the Irish side of my family. Nowadays these phrases are borderline oratorical in AmE.

@TimR - Your 'quaint' might be someone else's 'elegant'.

@MichaelHarvey Your Sackville-West quote is from eighty years ago.  Just sayin'.

I'd avoid 'these last days' because the phrase has a certain meaning ('the present') to some Christian fundies (the ones who believe the world will end imminently).

@TimR - must we all talk and write like Tik-Tokers and rappers now? Or communicate in grunts, as my dad used to say?

@MichaelHarvey No, we mustn't. I thought I was taking a page out of FumbleFingers's book by focusing on mainstream contemporary usage that works on either side of the Atlantic in most situations.

My apologies. I didn't read carefully enough. But it's much clearer after the edit, so i'll reverse that downvote. I don't think ELL should be promoting "quaint" usages, even if they might sometimes be classified as "elegant", so I think we agree on that score. Learners who actually need to ask about such stylistic choices would be better off simply avoiding anything they're doubtful about.

Cohen had gone to work for the acquiring company as part of a vestment schedule. In these past years, the job had become a golden cage. It paid well, if not extremely well—not the riches he might pursue if he were daring enough to try to start another company. But, more insidiously, it was easy. 'Shelter' By Nicole Krauss, New Yorker, September 26, 2022

It feels odd to exclude 'good' writing on the grounds that it might confuse learners.

@MichaelHarvey Literary quotes don't undermine my position on the tone the phrases have here in the US. Now, if the quote came from a speaker of AmE writing in The Atlantic or in the NYT or Washington Post, that would be different. That said, there's a wave of Anglophilia here at the moment. People are saying "bespoke" instead of "custom" and dropping phrases like "done and dusted". And  there's a chance we may have a king again.

@MichaelHarvey: I won't disagree with the proposition that your cited Nicole Krauss passage is  'good' writing. I even learnt something from it (well, from being connected to the Internet while I read it! ), since I didn't know the expression golden cage syndrome until now. Presumably modeled on golden hello and golden handshake...

...but I doubt any learner comfortable with Krauss's text would need to ask for stylistic advice here.
